# Javascript: Replace onChange event with string

Tags: javascript, moss

I am currently working within the confines of sharepoint 2007 and have some code that turns a dropdownlist into a combobox. What i have works perfectly fine, however this code is meant to be used by business analysts and content creators so it has to be as simple as possible. So i am condensing it into a function and all has gone swimmingly except for the onChange event.

I have managed to extract the original onChange event, though due to my dropdownlist i have to replace a parameter. So i convert it to a string, replace the parameter and need to reconvert it to a function a la:

```
var onChangeFunction = "function (){alert("your function has been called")}"    

//The function 'attachEvent' is not common javascript. It is a custom function
//that works for my combobox.
combobox.attachEvent("onChange",(function)onChangeFunction);
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: That's certainly not valid JavaScript.

Comment: If you are referring to the code, i am aware of that. I am trying to convey the sort of functionality i would like to achieve. If you are saying that what i want to achieve is not valid javascript then can you elaborate?

Comment: Try: `combobox.attachEvent("onChange",function(){alert("Test")});`

Comment: the attachEvent function is part of the code for my custom combobox. It isnt something that is out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new Function` but I think you are on a slippery slope playing with this.

```
var fn = new Function("{alert(\"your function has been called\")}")
combobox.attachEvent("onChange",fn);
```

Comment: Im pretty sure this is what i want.
And im well aware of the brittle nature of Javascript, but ill make sure to let the users know.

Comment: Javascript isn't "brittle", the way you are using it is. The solution offered by Rob W is much better than the one you have accepted (and functionaly equivalent).

Comment: @RobG, the question was not how to attach a function, but how to convert a string to a function.